# Why Array.length does not work with key string

Tags: arrays, javascript

I've been reading and doing some testing and found that the command. "Length" of the Array () javascript does not work when the array's keys are string. I found that to run this command, I use whole keys.

However, I wonder if any of you can tell me why this rule? Limitation of language, or specification of logic? Or, my mistake ...?

Thanks

Obs.: The key to my array is a string (name of component) but the values and the array of objects.

Declarating:

```
objElementos = new Array();
```

Object:

```
objElemento = function(Id){
this.Id        = $('#' + Id).attr('id');
this.Name      = $('#' + Id).attr('name');
this.CssLeft   = $('#' + Id).css('left');
this.CssBottom = $('#' + Id).css('bottom');
this.Parent    = $('#' + Id).parent().get(0);
this.Childs    = new Array();

this.addChild = function(IdObjChild) {
    try {
        if ($('#' + IdObjChild).attr('id') != '')
            this.Childs[$('#' + IdObjChild).attr('id')] = new objElemento(IdObjChild);
    } catch(err){ $('#divErrors').prepend('<p>' + err + '</p>'); }
}

this.getChildCount = function(){
    try {
        $('#divErrors').prepend('<p>' + this.Childs.length + '</p>');
        return this.Childs.length;
    } catch(err){ $('#divErrors').prepend('<p>' + err + '</p>'); }
}

this.updateCssLeft = function(CssPosition){
    try {
        $('#divErrors').prepend('<p>updateCssLeft:' + this.Id + ' / ' + this.CssLeft + '</p>');

        $('#' + this.Id).css('left',CssPosition);
        this.CssLeft = $('#' + this.Id).css('left');

        $('#divErrors').prepend('<p>updateCssLeft:' + this.Id + ' / ' + this.CssLeft + '</p>');         
    } catch(err){ $('#divErrors').prepend('<p>' + err + '</p>'); }
}

this.updateCssBottom = function(CssPosition){
    try {
        $('#divErrors').prepend('<p>updateCssBottom:' + this.Id + ' / ' + this.CssBottom + '</p>');

        $('#' + this.Id).css('bottom',CssPosition);
        this.CssBottom = $('#' + this.Id).css('bottom');

        $('#divErrors').prepend('<p>updateCssBottom:' + this.Id + ' / ' + this.CssBottom + '</p>');
    } catch(err){ $('#divErrors').prepend('<p>' + err + '</p>'); }
}
  }
```

Use:

```
objElementos['snaptarget'] = new objElemento('snaptarget');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using string "indexers" on an array, you are effectively treating it as an object and not an array, and tacking extra fields onto that object. If you are not using integer indexes, then there's not really much point in using the Array type and it makes more sense to use the Object type instead. You could count the fields as follows:

```
var c=0;
for(var fieldName in obj)
{
    c++;
}
```

Comment: That would be the only language that treats the array like this then, correct? I have heard that javascript is quite incomplete in object orientation. @spender

Comment: I'm not sure many other languages would allow use of a string to index an array (although the term index here is misapplied). It's more a job for Dictionary type collections.

Comment: now I'm declaring an array of objects, and adding elements (objects) to it. Otherwise there would be more correct to do this? - Code above. @spender

Comment: @Ph.E – I wouldn't consider JavaScript's implementation of OOP as incomplete; it's just different, as it's a [Prototype-based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming) language, opposed to [Class-based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class-based_programming).

Comment: Nice! Thanks by responding @Marcel Korpel.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question: is this behavior required by the design of javascript or is it browser dependent behavior...  that is will all ecma compliant browsers have the length property return the count of EXACTLY the number of integer keys...

Comment: quick note: you can count the length the same way as for objects:
`Object.keys(obj).length`

Answer (score 7):

Since arrays with key strings are **objects**, you can use:

```
Object.keys(objElementos).length
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because when you are using strings as your keys, you're really declaring an object, rather than an array. As such, there is no length attribute for objects.

Comment: They are all telling me that. Thanks. @Mike Sherov